# Computing investment returns on TD Ameritrade

Tags: investing, td-ameritrade

Vanguard has a dashboard that automatically computes and displays one's personal performance. It has a plot of Balances over time, and of Net Purchases and Withdrawals over time. Then, below this, it has a plot of Investment Returns over time, which is the difference between these two. It also computes the annualized rate of return (from Investment Returns) for various time periods (eg YTD).

Is there a way to obtain the same thing for one's TD Ameritrade portfolio? As far as I can tell, there is no dashboard that does this automatically. Am I wrong? And if I'm right, what's the most straightforward way to compute this manually?

Comment: I presume you mean short of having something like Quicken do it for you?

Comment: If you can't find it on the brokerage website, have a look at Excel XIRR function

Comment: @keshlam, yes, I don't have Quicken. But I do have Excel, so will try using XIRR if all else fails.

Comment: Have you asked TD whether they provide that info somewhere on the website?

Comment: I've not asked them, but I've searched their website and Google, finding nothing.